Python Chatbot not Fetching Values from JSON file
I am creating a chatbot in python using NLTK library and Keras. The chatbot will be trained on some conversational data that is stored in JSON file. Here is how it looks:
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "context": "",
      "patterns": ["Hello", "Hi there"],
      "responses": ["Hi there! What can I get for you?"],
      "tag": "greeting"
    },
    {
      "context": "",
      "patterns": ["I'd like to place an order", "Can I order now?", "What's on the menu?"],
      "responses": ["Of course! Would you like to see our menu?", "Sure! Here's our menu. What would you like to order?"],
      "tag": "order"
    },
    {
      "context": "",
      "patterns": ["I'd like a [item]", "Can I get [item] please", "I want to order [item]"],
      "responses": ["Sure, we have [item]. Anything else you'd like?", "Great choice! Would you like anything else with that?"],
      "tag": "item_order"
    }
  ]
}

After I train the model, it works perfectly on the general statements. But when I try to fetch item_name from the second JSON file, it is not fetching it correctly and gives me the same general response.
This is how the menu.json file looks like:
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "item": "Krunch Burger",
      "price": "Rs270",
      "tags": ["krunch burger", "burger", "chicken burger"]
    }
]
}

Here is my code:
# Importing libraries
import json
import string
import random
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

# Mounting the Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
data_root = '/content/drive/My Drive/ChatBot'  # Adjust the path accordingly

# Loading the combined dataset
data_file = open('intents.json').read()
data = json.loads(data_file)

# Extracting intents, patterns, and responses
words = [] 
classes = [] 
data_X = [] 
data_y = [] 

# Iterating over all the intents
for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern) 
        words.extend(tokens) 
        data_X.append(pattern) 
        data_y.append(intent["tag"])

    if intent["tag"] not in classes:
        classes.append(intent["tag"])

# Lemmatizing words
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in words if word not in string.punctuation]
words = sorted(set(words))
classes = sorted(set(classes))

# Text to Numbers
training = []
out_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for idx, doc in enumerate(data_X):
    bow = []
    text = lemmatizer.lemmatize(doc.lower())
    for word in words:
        bow.append(1) if word in text else bow.append(0)
    output_row = list(out_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(data_y[idx])] = 1
    training.append([bow, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training, dtype=object)
train_X = np.array(list(training[:, 0]))
train_Y = np.array(list(training[:, 1]))

# Neural Network Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_X[0]),), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_Y[0]), activation="softmax"))

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, epochs=150, verbose=1)

#7 Preprocessing the Input

def clean_text(text):
  tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
  tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens]
  return tokens

def bag_of_words(text, vocab):
  tokens = clean_text(text)
  bow = [0] * len(vocab)
  for w in tokens:
    for idx, word in enumerate(vocab):
      if word == w:
        bow[idx] = 1
  return np.array(bow)

def pred_class(text, vocab, labels):
  bow = bag_of_words(text, vocab)
  result = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0] #Extracting probabilities
  thresh = 0.5
  y_pred = [[indx, res] for indx, res in enumerate(result) if res > thresh]
  y_pred.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) #Sorting by values of probability in decreasing order
  return_list = []
  for r in y_pred:
    return_list.append(labels[r[0]]) #Contains labels(tags) for highest probability
  return return_list

# Load menu data from JSON file
menu_file = open('menu.json').read()
menu_data = json.loads(menu_file)

# Function to fetch menu item and price based on user query
def get_menu_item(query):
    print("Query:", query)
    query = query.lower()  
    for item in menu_data["menu"]:
        print("Item in menu:", item)
        if query in item["item"].lower():
            return item["item"], item["price"]
    return None, None

# Updated get_response function to handle menu-related queries
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json, menu_data):
    if len(intents_list) == 0:
        result = "Sorry! I don't understand."
    else:
        tag = intents_list[0]
        list_of_intents = intents_json["intents"]
        for i in list_of_intents:
            if i["tag"] == tag:
                if tag == 'menu':
                    query = ' '.join(intents_list[1:])
                    item_name, item_price = get_menu_item(query, menu_data)
                    if item_name and item_price:
                        result = f"{item_name} costs {item_price}."
                    else:
                        result = "Sorry, that item is not available in our menu."
                else:
                    result = random.choice(i["responses"])
                break
    return result

# Interacting with the chatbot
print("Press 0 if you don't want to chat with our ChatBot.")
while True:
    message = input("")
    if message == "0":
        break
    intents = pred_class(message, words, classes)
    result = get_response(intents, data, menu_data)
    print(result)

When I run it, it gives output like this:
Press 0 if you don't want to chat with our ChatBot.
how much does krunch burger cost?
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step
Sure! The price for [item] is $[price].

I need it to provide the item name instead of [item] and price instead of [price].
Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you.

It seems like you're having trouble retrieving the correct menu item name and price from your JSON data. Let's modify the get_menu_item function to properly fetch the item name and price based on the user query. We'll also update the get_response function to use the retrieved item name and price in the response.Example_codeIn this updated version, the get_menu_item function iterates through each item in the menu and checks if any of its tags match the user query

If a match is found, it returns the corresponding item name and price.
The get_response function then uses this retrieved item name and price to generate the response.
